# Ubuntu server support

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Usually I use Logmein to do tech support. Now the server is in Ubuntu server in the another city. Do we have similar software as Logmein ?

Added: I will use Windows to remote log into Ubuntu.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Linux servers are best administered from the command line.  You can use PuTTY on Windows to SSH to the Linux machine.  You will need to forward port 22/TCP from the router to the Linux machine.

Answer (score 0):

As cjc already said: best was is using the command line.

If you need graphical access you can use VNC:

1. There are some clients for this running under Windows. Please consult the Internet.
2. On the Ubuntu box you have to do [some preparation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC).